# How can I update / edit the value of objects in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of objects from the api, which looks like this:

```
[{
    "title": "demo",
    "eventType": "demo",
    "start": "2022-06-26T07:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2022-06-26T04:00:00.000Z"
...
},{}
]
```

I would like to create a new array with the same values but wrapping the start and end object values in a `new Date()` like this:

```
[{
    "title": "demo",
    "eventType": "demo",
    "start": new Date("2022-06-26T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "end": new Date("2022-06-26T04:00:00.000Z")
...
},{}
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the array to loop over each object and return a modified object.

```
const result = data.map(({ start, end, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  start: new Date(start),
  end: new Date(end)
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayA = [
    {
        "title": "demo",
        "eventType": "demo",
        "start": "2022-06-26T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2022-06-26T04:00:00.000Z"
    }
];

var arrayB = [];

for (let index = 0; index < arrayA.length; index++) {
    var element = arrayA[index];
    element.start = new Date(element.start);
    element.end = new Date(element.end);
    arrayB.push(element);
    console.log(arrayB);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const demo = [{
    "title": "demo",
    "eventType": "demo",
    "start": "2022-06-26T07:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2022-06-26T04:00:00.000Z"
}]
demo.map(obj => ({...obj,start:new Date(obj.start),end:new Date(obj.end)}))
```